# SEO metatag NOOPD and NOODP. Which one to use?

Tags: seo, metadata, meta-tags, google-search, meta

I was adding few more additional metatags for improving SEO of the website I am working on, however I have never used NOOPD or NOODP meta tags before and on searching about these metatags, I am a bit confused which one to use and what is the difference between these two?

so I was wondering which one is better or is there any difference between these two at all? 
`<meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="index, follow, all, noopd, noydir">` 
 or

```
<meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="index, follow, all, noodp, noydir">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `noodp`, because that is one of the [meta tags that Google understands](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en). As described at that page, this tag "prevents the alternative description from the ODP/DMOZ from being used".